# Can we have the reputation league shown in the user page like Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

Having been participating on Stack Overflow a bit recently, I've noticed this:

[image]

This doesn't seem to exist on Ask Different:

[image]

Can it be added?

Comment: Good question, is it because SO is a bit bigger? If you check http://stackexchange.com/sites you can see SO is (according to the image) 4 times bigger than AskDifferent.

Comment: @Robuust Yeah, but why does that mean that the statistic isn't shown here?

Comment: I have no idea, I'd like to see it too. But that was my point - maybe it's still in beta on SO? I don't know? Just guessing along with you.

Comment: Can a moderator flag it to development - or this needs to be reposted on meta.stackexchnage.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's been done — it now exists as of rev 2014.5.14.1605:

[image]

Comment: Showing too precise precision i.e. that should make more sense as ).2% and mine should be 1% rather than .98%

Comment: @Mark I guess it's using the same code as SO/etc where 0.01% is a fair few spots on the leaderboard.

Comment: SO seems to be rounded to 1 significant figure e.g. 2% which is why I noticed

Answer (score 2):

It seems only SO shows the rep. league.

Since SE has 115(!) Q&A sites all in all, I made a script (obviously :P) to look through each of them and check whether profile pages showed rep. league.

The result was that no other SE sites but SO showed it. To be extra sure, I also recorded total number of users for each site *and* number of users with actual RP change. And thus, I don't think it has anything to do with community size.

Just to give you an idea of community sizes on SE:

- SO has ~2.85 mill.
- Ask Ubuntu has ~181k
- Ask Different has ~54k
- Homebrew has 3.6k
- Italian has 445

So maybe the SE devs are just trying it out on their largest site? Doesn't seem to be by mistake that it only shows on SO.